# Can we deploy one Rails app to multiple servers at once with Capistrano?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, capistrano

I'm having a Rails app, and there is one reason that I have to deploy one app to multiple production hosts/servers.

Currently, I have to deploy one Rails app to two hosts. So, I have to do `cap production deploy` twice. And I have to comment out server line one after another.

```
# server 'host_1', user: 'my_user', roles: %w{app}
server 'host_2', user: 'my_user', roles: %w{app}
```

I have `config/deploy/production.rb` and `config/environments/production.rb`

```
Ruby 2.3.3
Rails 4.2.2
capistrano-rails 1.1.1
```

Comment: I had work in similar situations, in our case the problem was, the app architecture couldn't handle multiple companies. There were users, but each project represented a single company. In the long run, this turns into maintaining different machines, one for each company. It became costly and demoralizing for the dev team. Maybe budget constraints won't allow you to have the desired degree of control, but with time is better to do it as soon as you can.

Comment: @cutiko If I'm not wrong, your app is kind of SaaS, isn't it?

Comment: @PirungSeng it was SaaS

Comment: @cutiko are you using PostgreSQL for your database? I just wonder if your problem is about data storage, and not the servers.

Comment: @PirungSeng the problem was the database architecture, it wasnt modeled for supporting more customers (companies) to get a quick MVP. Is there anything you want to tell about your problem, maybe I can help?

Comment: @cutiko my question above is all I need.

Answer (score 2):

Cap is a remote multi-server automation tool. to achieve your goal, just keep both of the linens uncommented and you will be able to deploy to both servers

```
server 'host_1', user: 'my_user', roles: %w{app}
server 'host_2', user: 'my_user', roles: %w{app}
```